# Abbott 5.2.8(d) without mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis

It is suggested in Abbott, understanding analysis 2nd edition exercise 5.2.8(d)

(c) If $f$ is differenciable on an interval containing zero and if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f'(x)=L$, then it must be that $L = f'(0)$.

(d) Repeat conjecture (c) but drop the assumption that $f'(0)$ necessarily exists. If $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \in \mathbb{R} -\{0\}$ and if $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f'(x) = L$, then $f'(0)$ exists and equals $L$.

When I try to prove (d), I think $f$ is also continuous at 0 because Abbott just says "drop the existance of $f'(0)$" and if we omit the continuity at 0 of $f$, it is very easy. But I cannot prove this propostion without MVT(This exercise is front of MVT). Is it intended? Or isn't it Abbott's intention to add continuity at 0?

Comment: If $f$ is differentiable on an interval containing $0$ it needs to be continuous at $0$ (otherwise it wouldnt be differentiable).

Comment: What you said is (c).

Comment: Does (d) mean that $f$ is differentiable in a neighborhood of $0$ except possibily $0$?

Comment: As I understood, "although we do not assume the differentiability at 0, we can derive the differentiability at 0 with given assumption".

Comment: Somehow you must use completeness (Extreme Value Theorem, Rolle's Theorem, Mean Value Theorem, or De l'Hospital, or some version of them), because without it, the conclusion would be false. It is easy to constuct counterxamples in $\Bbb Q$, for example.

Comment: What was your approach in proving (c) without MVT or de l'Hospital? Note that this is also false in $\Bbb Q$.